# When compiling a line counting program in Solaris an extra three lines are being as opposed to MacOSX

Tags: c, macos, unix, solaris

I wrote the following code under MacOSX in XCode. When moving the code over to a Solaris Server three extra lines are being counted and I can not figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 281 // 281 is a prime number!!
char words[4][MAXLINE]; // words array to hold menu items
char displayfilename[4][MAXLINE]; //filename array to hold filename for display function
char exit_choice[4][MAXLINE]; //for user interaction and end of each function
int i; //standard array variable
int loop = 1; //control variable for my loop
int main() 

{ 
    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s", displayfilename[i]);
    FILE *fp; 
    int clo_c , clo_nc, clo_nlines; 
    fp = fopen(*displayfilename,"r"); // open for reading */  

    if ( fp == NULL ) 
    { 
        printf("Cannot open for reading!\n");

    } 

    clo_c = getc( fp ) ;            
    while (  clo_c != EOF ) 
    { 
        if (clo_c == '\n')
            clo_nlines++ ;

        clo_nc++ ;  
        clo_c = getc ( fp ); 
    } 

    fclose( fp ); 

    if ( clo_nc != 0 ) 
    {

        printf("There are %d lines in this file.\n", clo_nlines);
    }
    else 
        printf("File is empty, exiting!\n");
}
```

Can anyone explain to me Solaris is adding three to clo_nlines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't initialize clo_nlines - therefore you got 'undefined behavior'.

Declaring a variable in C doesn't set its value to anything - it just allocates some memory for that variable, and whatever junk happens to be in that bit (well, not bit, but you get the idea >.>) of memory is what the variable starts out as.

Comment: I assigned the value of zero to these variables and that corrected the problem under solaris. Thank You very much!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.

First one, from a bulletproof-code point of view, is @Zilchonum's point, that `clo_nc` and `clo_nlines` aren't being initialized.  In old C, that means you don't have any idea what's in them to start with and so don't have any idea what you'll end with.

However, later C standards define that uninitialized variables are set to 0, so that's probably not it unless you're setting the compiler to earlier behavior with flags.

More likely is Auri's point, that different machines use different newline standards.  However, I believe that Mac OS/X uses a single character for newline, just as Solaris does.

Which brings us to the file itself.  Try using `oc -c` to see what's actually in the file.  my guess is that you'll find the file on one system is `\r\n` newlines, but on the other system has `\n` newlines, probably as a result of the settings of the file transfer program you used.  It has probably converted to UNIX format on one but not the other.

Comment: "However, later C standards define that uninitialized variables are set to 0" - I've never heard of any such standard.

Comment: The standard only states that static variables are initialized to 0 or NULL, and that "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you're not counting crlf as two linefeeds?